# What is the namespace to get size and length of a file (see file explorer as an example)

Tags: .net-core

This is an example of my directory.  I would like to get the size and the length of the each via c# and dotnet core 5.0.
[image: sample of my directory]

Answer (score 0):

[`FileInfo.Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.length?view=net-5.0) is what you need. In documentation you will find also sample code.

Comment: That will be the size of the file.  The length is going to be the duration which is the one I am looking for.  The terminology is a confuse regarding Length vs Size and FileInfo property length.

Answer (score 0):

`long length = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length;`  return the length of file in bytes.

Comment: That will be the size of the file.  The length is going to be the duration which is the one I am looking for.  The terminology is a confuse regarding Length vs Size and FileInfo property length.

Answer (score 0):

This is a piece of my code using shell32.dll to obtain duration of a mediafile.  It works if my application is running as an exe file. However, I run it under IIS, it doesn't work.

```
private static List<ClassMediaMetaData> GetFilesSingleDir(String folder)
        {
            TimeSpan dur = TimeSpan.Zero;
            Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
            Shell32.Folder objFolder = shell.NameSpace(folder);
            List<ClassMediaMetaData> list = new();
            list.Clear();
            foreach (FolderItem2 item in objFolder.Items())
            {
                if (!item.IsFolder)
                {
                    ClassMediaMetaData md = new ClassMediaMetaData();
                    dur = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(item.ExtendedProperty("System.Media.Duration") / 10000000);
                    md.Duration = dur.Duration();
                    md.FullFileName = item.Name;
                    md.FullPath = folder;
                    list.Add(md);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Is Shell32.DLL for desktop application only or it can be running in the IIS as well.  If it does, what are the requirements to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: This is the error message from IIS:System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Shell32.Shell'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{286E6F1B-7113-4355-9562-96B7E9D64C54}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CastHelpers.ChkCastAny(Void* toTypeHnd, Object obj)